# Redhat Openshift Service on AWS (ROSA) installation adds an unprotected ingress security rule, which is revoked by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift

I am trying to install an open shift cluster on AWS using ROSA plugin.

Cluster creation is successfully triggered and 3 masters, 2 controller, 1 bootstrapper VMs are created.

Installation continues & open shift installer tries to add an unprotected ingress rule for SSH, which is revoked by AWS due to a security risk.

Security rule added by OCP installer:-

*•  Protocol: tcp
•   Port range: 22 - 22
•   IP range: 0.0.0.0/0

Action done:

The security group contained an ingress rule allowing unrestricted access from any source IP (0.0.0.0/0) to TCP port 22 (SSH) or 3389 (RDP) or all ports. This rule has been revoked to keep your instances and account secure. Unrestricted access to these ports is considered a high security risk.*

Due to this, open shift cluster installation fails and installer re-tries cluster creation again.

Is there anyway to provide a more restricted firewall rule instead of 0.0.0.0, so that AWS doesn't revoke it & installation is successful? or if anyone has faced this issue, please suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi @user18782338, all ROSA clusters come with Premium Support through Red Hat at https://access.redhat.com. I suggest that you open a support case to help troubleshoot this further.

Comment: With that said, it's unlikely that AWS is revoking the security group, but possibly some corporate automation for your AWS organization. Currently the security group is created by the OpenShift Installer, and not something that ROSA is doing specifically. The SSH ingress is only used for installation troubleshooting by Red Hat SRE as needed: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/support/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-installations.html#monitoring-installation-progress_troubleshooting-installations